# React-Native App not running in Release mode and crashing on launch on test flight

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight

React-Native iOS App Archives successfully and uploads to Testflight but when you launch it, it just displays the splash screen then crashes

I tried checking the Testflight crash logs and they are no logs being displayed in Xcode. Im running an old react-native app, Here are my dependencies:

```
"appcenter": "2.6.1",
        "axios": "0.19.2",
        "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
        "bugsnag-react-native": "2.23.6",
        "contentful": "7.13.1",
        "date-holidays": "1.4.12",
        "expo": "36.0.0",
        "expo-av": "8.0.0",
        "expo-barcode-scanner": "8.0.0",
        "expo-camera": "8.0.0",
        "expo-contacts": "8.0.0",
        "expo-font": "8.0.0",
        "expo-local-authentication": "8.0.0",
        "expo-localization": "8.0.0",
        "expo-location": "8.0.0",
        "expo-secure-store": "8.0.0",
        "google-libphonenumber": "3.2.6",
        "i18n-js": "3.5.1",
        "lodash": "4.17.15",
        "moment": "2.24.0",
        "prop-types": "15.7.2",
        "react": "16.9.0",
        "react-dom": "16.9.0",
        "react-native": "0.61.4",
        "react-native-android-open-settings": "1.3.0",
        "react-native-animatable": "1.3.3",
        "react-native-awesome-card-io": "0.8.2",
        "react-native-code-push": "6.1.0",
        "react-native-fast-image": "7.0.2",
        "react-native-firebase": "~5.6.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.5.1",
        "react-native-get-location": "2.2.1",
        "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
        "react-native-in-app-review": "3.2.2",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.1",
        "react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
        "react-native-qrcode-svg": "6.0.3",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
        "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
        "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
        "react-native-svg": "11.0.1",
        "react-native-swipeout": "2.3.6",
        "react-native-unimodules": "0.7.0",
        "react-native-view-pdf": "0.13.2",
        "react-native-web": "0.11.7",
        "react-native-webview": "8.1.2",
        "react-navigation": "4.1.1",
        "react-navigation-drawer": "2.3.4",
        "react-navigation-stack": "2.1.1",
        "react-navigation-tabs": "2.7.0",
        "react-redux": "7.2.0",
        "redux": "4.0.5",
        "redux-form": "8.3.0",
        "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
        "sha1": "1.1.1",
        "uuid": "3.4.0",
        "validator": "12.2.0"
```

these are the logs i'm getting on xcode, I can't make much sense of them:

```
2023-07-14 20:39:38.128415+0200 Bootlegger[37801:3500119] Sent 3 sessions to Bugsnag
2023-07-14 20:39:38.129611+0200 Bootlegger[37801:3500202] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C4.1.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2023-07-14 20:39:38.134973+0200 Bootlegger[37801:3500202] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C4.1.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2023-07-14 20:39:38.138497+0200 Bootlegger[37801:3500119] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke [C4] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2023-07-14 20:39:38.138727+0200 Bootlegger[37801:3500119] TCP Conn 0x600001879680 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2023-07-14 20:39:38.350679+0200 Bootlegger[37801:3500125] Connection 6: received failure notification
2023-07-14 20:39:38.350889+0200 Bootlegger[37801:3500125] Connection 6: failed to connect 12:8, reason -1
2023-07-14 20:39:38.351000+0200 Bootlegger[37801:3500125] Connection 6: encountered error(12:8)
2023-07-14 20:39:38.352079+0200 Bootlegger[37801:3500203] Task <D8BD8504-EFD4-48D8-9CB0-6D50D1330A00>.<2> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1003 [12:8])
2023-07-14 20:39:38.353058+0200 Bootlegger[37801:3500202] Task <D8BD8504-EFD4-48D8-9CB0-6D50D1330A00>.<2> finished with error [-1003] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002677b10 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0[802.11], _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDownloadTask <D8BD8504-EFD4-48D8-9CB0-6D50D1330A00>.<2>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDownloadTask <D8BD8504-EFD4-48D8-9CB0-6D50D1330A00>.<2>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/co.za.wigroup.bootleggers/settings?build_version=4&display_version=3.1&instance=96d9f8a4413b4b766379fe976e5437d5e51b411c&source=1, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/co.za.wigroup.bootleggers/settings?build_version=4&display_version=3.1&instance=96d9f8a4413b4b766379fe976e5437d5e51b411c&source=1, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}
2023-07-14 20:39:38.360868+0200 Bootlegger[37801:3500202] [Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-6 "(null)" UserInfo={retryLimit=1, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/co.za.wigroup.bootleggers/settings?build_version=4&display_version=3.1&instance=96d9f8a4413b4b766379fe976e5437d5e51b411c&source=1}
INFO : BSG_KSCrash.m (262): -[BSG_KSCrash sendAllReportsWithCompletion:]: Sending 6 crash reports
INFO : BSG_KSCrashReport.c (1557): void bsg_kscrashreport_writeStandardReport(BSG_KSCrash_Context *const, const char *const): Writing crash report to ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/68A38606-C7DF-4F17-B6E1-866E938E96C6/data/Containers/Data/Application/AC1BDAAB-5968-4FC1-89C3-C1766695F27F/Library/Caches/KSCrashReports/Bootlegger/Bootlegger-CrashReport-3B856092-F97F-4069-A23F-420CBCFAF3E9.json
ERROR: BSG_KSMach.c (172): _Bool bsg_ksmachfillState(const thread_t, const thread_state_t, const thread_state_flavor_t, const mach_msg_type_number_t): thread_get_state: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
ERROR: BSG_KSCrashReport.c (384): struct __darwin_mcontext64 *bsg_kscrw_i_getMachineContext(const BSG_KSCrash_SentryContext *const, const thread_t, struct __darwin_mcontext64 *const): Failed to fetch machine state for thread 1795
2023-07-14 20:39:40.674279+0200 Bootlegger[37801:3500125] Reports sent.
INFO : BSG_KSCrash.m (262): -[BSG_KSCrash sendAllReportsWithCompletion:]: Sending 0 crash reports
```

Comment: Showing the dependencies is of no use. Try running it within Xcode but in release mode instead of the default debug mode. Then if it crashes you'll be able to see what's going on.

Comment: @Gruntcakes i have updated my question to include the XCode logs

Comment: Did you *specifically* run in release mode in Xcode? The point of doing that is to see if it will also crash when running in Xcode compared to running from a Testflight installation (when you add the app to TestFlight its a release build, when you run in Xcode its a debug build, often there are bugs that only appear in release builds and not in debug builds, but you can change the Xcode behavior to be a release build when your run it). I don't see any crash occuring in the log, your goal is to try and see if you can reproduce the crash when running with Xcode.

Comment: @Gruntcakes yes i was running in release mode, i have tried both Release mode via the Xcode Scheme and Release configuration via the command line and i get the exact same result

Comment: Stuff in the log looks like its for after the crash has occurred, not at the time of the crash. I can see something About crashlytics in that log, do you have that set up and are able to see the crash report in the Crashlytics console? I also see stuff about Bugsnag, same question are you able to see info about the crash on the Bugsnap website?